# handle data in LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

If I work with tables (using react-tabele in my case), which store lot of pages of content.

When I first open first page and put that data in localStorage, then open second page and put that data to localStorage, then open third and store data in localStorage.

How should I handle it in reverse?

When I go back to second page, should I try to get data from localStorage() without sending request for those data?

Just bring it back from localStorage and render it?

If someone can give me example of using it in example similar like my case.

I saw mdn example, but they just wanted to show when you close tab you can inherit your old setup.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you asking here. To get data from local-storage: `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('name'))` then do whatever you need to do with it

Comment: I know how to get data from localStorage

Comment: Okay, so what exactly do you need to do with that data?

Comment: What do you mean by "without sending request for those data"? Once you put the data in local storage, you don't need to do anything else to use it.

Comment: I know that also :)

Comment: If you know all this stuff, then what's your question? Just get the data and do whatever you want with it, such as rendering it in a table.

Comment: Local storage is a general purpose mechanism. How you use it depend's on your application's needs. MDN was just showing one example of the way to use it.

Comment: First step: 
Send request to fetch data, after that put that data in localStorage. ( all data from first page are in localStorage)
Repeat all steps for second page.
And for third.

And then go backwards. (Open again second, and then first page).
How should I do it?

Is it good approach to get data from localStorage, without sending again request for same data, cause we have it in our localStorage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, it's something related to caching your data in localStorage.
You can save timestamp together when you save the data to localStorage.
And when you arrive at that page again, you could check the timestamp and decide if you will send request or reuse the data in localStorage.

For example:

```
// when you save the data to localStorage
localStorage.setItem(KEY, JSON.stringify({
   data: YOUR_DATA,
   ts: Date.now()
}));
...
// when you read the data from localStorage
// here try/catch is used because JSON.parse will be error
// when the localStorage item is nothing or incorrect json string
try {
    const { data, ts } = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(KEY));
    
    if (Date.now() - +ts < SOME_SPECIFIC_TIMESTAMP) {
         // use data
    } else {
         // send api
    }
} catch (err) {
    // send api
}
```

However it depends on why you save the data to localStorage.

Comment: Yes you understand correctly, what I mean. But if I save timestamp, together with data, how I can use it and for which purpose?

For Example: 
var currentDate = new Date();
var timestamp = currentDate.getDate()

localStorage.setItem({timestamp, myBigData})

Comment: I updated my answer, you use it when you dont want to send same api requests in 1 hour, for example.

Comment: Ok, thanks for this answer with example!!
And last:
Is this approach correct way of thinking in your opinion?

Comment: yeah I think so :)

Comment: np, you can mark the question as correct if it worked